# Alignment of items in a Java Applet JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, grouplayout

[image]

I'm trying to get the top right square to be the same width as the two below it and I'd like to get the JTextArea below to match width as well. Any ideas?

It seems like no matter what I set the sizes to it's doing whatever it wants. For instance the Output JTextArea is set to just one column. The top image is (700x250) and the two half-images are (350x250).

```
public class MyApplet extends Applet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextArea input_data;
    private JTextArea input_jmax;
    private JTextArea input_gibbs;
    private JTextArea input_burnin;
    private JTextArea output_text;
    private JLabel output_graph;
    private JLabel output_burn1;
    private JLabel output_burn2;
    private static Graphics g=null;

    public void init () {
        //INPUT
        this.input_data = new JTextArea("Enter Data", 30, 30);
        JScrollPane data_pane= new JScrollPane(input_data);
        this.input_jmax = new JTextArea("Polya-Tree Levels", 1, 30);
        this.input_gibbs = new JTextArea("Gibbs Iterates", 1, 30);
        this.input_burnin = new JTextArea("Burnin", 1, 30);
        //OUTPUT
        Dimension D;
        D = new Dimension(700, 250);
        Image start;

        this.output_text = new JTextArea("####################Output####################",15,1);
        this.output_text.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane output_pane= new JScrollPane(output_text);

        this.output_burn1 = new JLabel();
        D = new Dimension(345,250);
        start = createImage((int) D.getWidth(), (int) D.getHeight());
        g = start.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,345,250);
        output_burn1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(start));

        this.output_burn2 = new JLabel();
        D = new Dimension(345, 250);
        start = createImage((int) D.getWidth(), (int) D.getHeight());
        g = start.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,345,250);
        output_burn2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(start));

        this.output_graph = new JLabel();
        start = createImage((int) D.getWidth(), (int) D.getHeight());
        g = start.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,700,250);
        output_graph.setIcon(new ImageIcon(start));

        //BUTTON
        JButton b = new JButton("Process Data");

        //set size

        setSize(1200, 600);
        setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        JPanel burninPanel = new JPanel();
        burninPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(burninPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        burninPanel.add(output_burn1);
        burninPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
        burninPanel.add(output_burn2);
        /*
        //Create Input Side
         * */
        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
        inputPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(inputPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        inputPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        inputPanel.add(data_pane);
        inputPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        inputPanel.add(input_jmax);
        inputPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        inputPanel.add(input_gibbs);
        inputPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        inputPanel.add(input_burnin);
        inputPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        inputPanel.add(b);

        //Create Output Side
        JPanel outputPanel = new JPanel();
        outputPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        outputPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(outputPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        outputPanel.add(output_graph);
        outputPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        outputPanel.add(burninPanel);
        outputPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        outputPanel.add(output_pane);


        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        this.setVisible(true); 
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(this);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(inputPanel)
                        .addComponent(outputPanel)
                        ) 
                );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                        .addComponent(inputPanel)
                        .addComponent(outputPanel)
                        )
                );

        this.setLayout(layout);        
        this.setVisible(true);

        // specify that action events sent by the
        // button or the input TextField should be handled 
        // by the same CapitalizerAction object
        Multiplicity ca = new Multiplicity(input_data, input_jmax, input_gibbs, input_burnin, output_text,output_graph);
        b.addActionListener(ca);
        //this.input.addActionListener(ca);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a custom panel, onto which you can paint your graph.  Add this, using an appropriate layout manager, to your applet.  You might consider going the rest of us in the 21st century and at least consider using Swing over AWT, oh wait, you're mixing AWT and Swing components...that'll end nicely...

Comment: Just know, there is a difference between AWT and Swing components, AWT components don't play nicely on Swing components, best to avoid mixing them ;)

Comment: Is this better? Any change you know how to get the second column using the group layout? The hard thing is that the grids aren't of the same size... am I even barking up the right tree? @MadProgrammer

Comment: You 3 core areas, left, middle, right.  Layout each area on it's own `JPanel`.  Once you've got that, you could then use a `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout` to add these three panels to the main UI

Comment: Okay! We're up and running with the swing elements in a group layout. I'm still having the same alignment problem, except that now there's no padding between the text areas either. @MadProgrammer

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why mix Swing with AWT?   The Swing applet is `java.swing.JApplet`..

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I agree with the teaching part of things. I'm a statistics grad student. We usually create R packages for our projects. The model I'm currently working on is for Biologist - they, in general, do not enjoy coding. This is a nice way for them to be able to utilize this code without the steep learning curve of learning how to code. That being said, I'm open to other suggestions! @AndrewThompson

Comment: *"This is a nice way for them to be able to utilize this code without the steep learning curve of learning how to code."*  There is a steep learning curve to developing and deploying applets.  They are much harder than (`JFrame` based) applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can't add an image of the same size to the stack. Instead of placing all the items an "outputPanel" I put each one in it's own panel and added all the panels to the outputPanel. Such a stupid thing!

```
public class MyApplet extends Applet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextArea input_data;
    private JTextArea input_jmax;
    private JTextArea input_gibbs;
    private JTextArea input_burnin;
    private JTextArea output_text;
    private JLabel output_graph;
    private JLabel output_burn1;
    private JLabel output_burn2;
    private static Graphics g=null;

    public void init () {
        //INPUT
        this.input_data = new JTextArea("Data", 30, 30);
        JScrollPane data_pane= new JScrollPane(input_data);
        this.input_jmax = new JTextArea("Polya-Tree Levels", 1, 30);
        this.input_gibbs = new JTextArea("Gibbs Iterates", 1, 30);
        this.input_burnin = new JTextArea("Burn-in", 1, 30);


        //OUTPUT
        Dimension D;
        Image start;

        this.output_burn1 = new JLabel();
        D = new Dimension(345,200);
        start = createImage((int) D.getWidth(), (int) D.getHeight());
        g = start.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,345,200);
        output_burn1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(start));

        this.output_burn2 = new JLabel();
        D = new Dimension(345, 200);
        start = createImage((int) D.getWidth(), (int) D.getHeight());
        g = start.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,345,200);
        output_burn2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(start));

        this.output_graph = new JLabel();
        D = new Dimension(700, 200);
        start = createImage((int) D.getWidth(), (int) D.getHeight());
        g = start.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,700,200);
        output_graph.setIcon(new ImageIcon(start));

        //BUTTON
        JButton b = new JButton("Process Data");

        //set size
        setSize(1200, 600);
        setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        //Create Input Side
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        buttonPanel.add(b);
        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
        inputPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(inputPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        inputPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        inputPanel.add(data_pane);
        inputPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        inputPanel.add(input_jmax);
        inputPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        inputPanel.add(input_gibbs);
        inputPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        inputPanel.add(input_burnin);
        inputPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        inputPanel.add(buttonPanel);

        //Create Output Side
        JPanel estPanel = new JPanel();
        estPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        estPanel.add(output_graph);

        JPanel burninPanel = new JPanel();
        burninPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        burninPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(burninPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        burninPanel.add(output_burn1);
        burninPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
        burninPanel.add(output_burn2);

        this.output_text = new JTextArea("",15,1);
        this.output_text.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane output_pane= new JScrollPane(output_text);

        JPanel outputPanel = new JPanel();
        outputPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        outputPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(outputPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        outputPanel.add(estPanel);
        outputPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        outputPanel.add(burninPanel);
        outputPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        outputPanel.add(output_pane);


        this.setVisible(true); 
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(this);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(inputPanel)
                        .addComponent(outputPanel)
                        ) 
                );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(LEADING)
                        .addComponent(inputPanel)
                        .addComponent(outputPanel)
                        )
                );
        this.setLayout(layout);        
        this.setVisible(true);

        // specify that action events sent by the
        // button or the input TextField should be handled 
        // by the same CapitalizerAction object
        Multiplicity ca = new Multiplicity(input_data, input_jmax, input_gibbs, input_burnin, output_text,output_graph,output_burn1,output_burn2);
        b.addActionListener(ca);
    }
}
```

Comment: `setSize(1200, 600);`  The first thing to learn about applets is that their size is set in the HTML that loads them.  An applet should never try to set how much space they occupy in a web page.  And again, don't mix Swing with AWT.  If the 'template' is AWT based (`java.applet.Applet`) it would be best to stick to AWT components throughout.

Comment: Thank you for the input - I actually have a more algorithmic/mathy comp sci undergraduate degree. We didn't touch applets and though it's been 6 or so years I thought I'd try to make the leap. I just set the size so it'd pop up in the debugger before I post it to the internet.